# Can the Senate vote again on the bill to fund "The Wall" after the new members of Senate are sworn in?

Tags: united-states, senate, legislation, trump-wall

Currently the House has approved and signed a bill funding "the wall."

Senate has not approved.  New members are sworn in January.  Can the bill then be approved and submitted to be signed by the president?

Answer (score 6):

No. All pending legislation expires at the end of the 115th Congress. Even if it didn't, the Senate still wouldn't have 60 votes for a wall.

Comment: The new House probably wouldn't approve the current bill, either.

Comment: @jamesqf Although if pending legislation _didn't_ expire, it'd be theoretically possible for the new Senate to approve the old House's bill as-is, and deny the new House any opportunity to get involved.  But it does, so that's not actually possible.